# Help to customize my own tooltip corners and improve positioning

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

for first time i want to use my own tooltip script (because i don't know how to set image corners in qtip/qtip2 )

I created this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6BjWY/14/ and its 'working' (but not the way I expected)

here is an image of what i would like:

[image]

Any idea why the left, right, bottom images (now only using colors as bg) are not displayed?? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is closer.  Have fun with it. http://jsfiddle.net/6Rthj/

Basically all you needed to do was use absolute positioning and % widths/heights

Comment: Yeeey! Looks much better! Any way to position it according to the mouse instead of '.miTooltip' ????

Comment: how are my new Hero! it works great but in IE it doesn't respect the height and the .bottom is like 20 pixels moved to the top. Would you fix it with hacks or you have a better idea??